# Is there a way to make a search bar like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i am making a search bar with javascript and jquery and i loop through a list of objects and an if statement checks if the input value includes something in my array. Then if it does include the item will get added to a select as an option and if the user removes the characters in the input the list would be empty.

But i can't seem to make it work.

This is what i've got:

```
<input class="type" value="" />
<select class="opties">

</select>

$('.type').on('keyup', function() {
        let input = $('.type').val().toLowerCase();
        let pc = ['Processor', 'Ram', 'Videokaart', 'Voeding', 'SSD', 'Fans'];

        for(let i=0; i<pc.length;i++) {
            if(!pc[i].toLowerCase().includes(input)) { 
                $('.opties').remove(pc[i])
            } else {
                $('.opties').append("<option>"+pc[i]+"</option>")
            }
            if(input == '') {
                $('.opties').empty();
            }
        }
    })
```

The output right now is a few options that are duplicates of each other.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [Minimal reroducalbe example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can assit you.

Comment: `if($('.opties').children())` will always be truthy. It's a jQuery object and objects are truthy. Passing artbitrary text to remove() doesn't make sense either

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Updated the question is this enough? @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to `filter()` your array and insert new options each update.

You may want to *throttle* or *debounce* this to give user time to type

```js
let $sel = $('.opties')

$('.type').on('input', function() {
  $sel.empty()

  let input = $('.type').val().trim().toLowerCase();
  let pc = ['Processor', 'Ram', 'Videokaart', 'Voeding', 'SSD', 'Fans'];

  if (input.length) {
    const filtered = pc.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(input));
    const opts = filtered.map(v => new Option(v, v));
    $sel.append(opts)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="type" value="" />
<select class="opties">

</select>
```

Comment: @skobaljic There is only one append. Not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const pc = ['Processor', 'Ram', 'Videokaart', 'Voeding', 'SSD', 'Fans'];

$('.type').on('keyup', function() {
  const input = $('.type').val().toLowerCase();
  for (let option of pc) {
    $(`.opties option[name='${option}']`).remove()
    if (option.toLowerCase().includes(input) && input.length)
      $('.opties').append(`<option name='${option}'>${option}</option>`)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="type" value="" />
<select class="opties"></select>
```

---

Main problem is that `$('.opties').remove(pc[i])` is not working. You are trying to remove the select-element instead of its children. Give them name attributes, this is a good way to go!

Comment: I wouldn't give them different names, but maybe IDs... Still you should explain why his code is wrong, what the problem is?

Comment: This code does work and is exactly what i am looking for and i understand how your code works. Thanks for your reply and help but the next time explain your code.